# An interesting property of positive definite and essentially non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ be a symmetric matrix that is

1. positive definite;
2. essentially non-negative, i.e., all the off-diagonal entries are non-negative.

I observe the following phenomenon: for any vector $v \ge 0$ such that $Sv > 0$ (element-wisely), the following matrix

$$ T:= S^{-1} - \text{diag}\left(\frac{(v)_i}{(Sv)_i}\right) $$

is positive semidefinite. Here, $(v)_i$ stands for the $i$-th coordinate of vector $v$.

I can prove for small $k$ (e.g., $k=2$ or $3$) via brute force. But I do not have a good idea how to prove for general $k$. I did run some simulations and the claim is very likely to be true.

Any comments or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: If $S$ is PD, aren't its diagonal entries non-negative?

Comment: Yes. How to proceed then?

Comment: First, make sure that my assertion is correct.  If so, then you have a doubly non-negative matrix.

Comment: Yes. Is there anything special about doubly non-negative matrix that can be used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $u\circ v$ and $u\oslash v$ the Hadamard product and entrywise division of two vectors respectively. Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{v\oslash Sv})$ and $u=\sqrt{v\circ Sv}$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
DSDu
&=DS\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{v\oslash Sv})(\sqrt{v\circ Sv})\\
&=DSv\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{v\oslash Sv})Sv\\
&=\sqrt{v\circ Sv}\\
&=u.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $DSD$ is nonnegative, $u>0$ is its Perron vector and $\rho(DSD)=1$. As $DSD$ is also real symmetric, we have $DSD\preceq I$. Therefore $0\prec S\preceq D^{-2}$ and $T=S^{-1}-D^2\succeq0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it must have something to do with the Perron-Frobenius theorem, just didn’t find a proper way to apply it…